# Weird behavior in the execution sequence. Threads, async and await included

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, async-await

This code is mainly Image Processing, but what I am experiencing is not a syntax error "We think it's threading thing". I am working on an application that I did not write. These codes are several .cpp/c# files. It was working fine but out of a sudden it started to do this strange behavior.

Usually, user takes a picture and at `line 85`, before the `switch()`, the control step into several functions to end up in the last file (1->6). When this last file (6) ends execution, the control flows back (6->1) and we retrieve a "`case`" to the first file to then enter the `switch()`, execute and continue.

1:

```
     private async void measureButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                // .. 
                // some code above
                var result = await ((CaptureViewModel)DataContext).ProcessMeasurement(); // line 85

            switch (result) // line 87 <<< Here the switch executes before line 85 finishes executing
            {
                    // some  code and cases below
                    // ....
```

2:

```
public async Task<AnalyzeCode> ProcessMeasurement()
{
    if (currentSession.Type == SessionType.Calibration)
        return await TakeCalibrationImage();

    return AnalyzeCode.NoSessionSelected;
}
```

3:

```
public async Task<AnalyzeCode> TakeCalibrationImage()
{
    if (calibrationData.Count < maxCalibrationImages)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = await cameraController.TakeMeasurement(currentSession.Calibration, SessionType.Calibration);
            // some code below
            // ..
```

4:

```
public async Task<Measurement> TakeMeasurement(Calibration calibration, SessionType type)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case SessionType.Calibration:
                    // some code above
                    // ..
                    return await cameraClient.AnalyzeNextCalibrationAsync(); // line 518 Here it throws an exception error
                    // some code below
                    //..
```

5:

```
IObservable<Measurement>^ Client::AnalyzeNextCalibrationAsync()
{
    return Observable::ObserveOn(
        Observable::SubscribeOn(
            Observable::Create<Measurement>(
                gcnew Func<IObserver<Measurement>^, Action^>(
                gcnew AnalyzeNextCalibrationSubscribeFactory(this),
                &AnalyzeNextCalibrationSubscribeFactory::AnalyzeNext)),
            Scheduler::TaskPool),
        Scheduler::TaskPool);
}
class on_next_functor_3
{
    public:
           void operator ()(const tuple<frame, frame>& pair) const
           {
                Action<Measurement>^ on_next_delegate = this->on_next_delegate;
                on_next_delegate(ConvertToCalibrationMeasurement(pair));
           }
};
```

6:

```
Measurement ConvertToCalibrationMeasurement(const tuple<frame, frame>& pair)
{
        // ...
        // more code above
    auto result1 = find_calibration_pattern(master_image); // line 386
    auto result2 = find_calibration_pattern(slave_image); // line 387
// ..
// some code
// ..
    return Measurement( // line 401
        masterImage,
        slaveImage,
        ConvertToDateTime(master.time),
        ConvertToTargets(result));
} // end of the function
```

Now here is the recent weird behavior. The control enters 6 ans starts executing statement by statement, then suddenly the control jumps back to 4, throws an error and all the way back to the beginning and executes the `switch()` which pops the error on the screen. Then, the control goes back to `line 387` in the very end and continues with executing that function. So technically it's executing the `switch()` in 1 before the previous statement finishes executing. Then whatever the result at in the very end is, won't be useful since our "fail" case already executed.

Does anyone on earth knows why this would happen? where would this problem generate? and how to fix it? Thanks

**Edit:**

The Output window shows this once the prompt error (from the `switch()`) pops:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Reactive.Linq.dll
The thread 0x1574 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in App.exe
```

And this happens in the `catch()` of file 4 line 518

The Thread windows shows that the `Main Thread` has the control (Yellow arrow) all the way from file 1->4. However, once file 4 calls 5->6, the `Main Thread` loses the control and the "yellow arrow" goes to a `Worker Thread` executing 6. Now, while executing  6, the `Main Thread` takes back the control into 4, throws an exception and executes the `catch()` but then loses the control to go back to that `Worker Thread` and continue executing 6.. Is this normal? I never worked with threads but this is not logical and I have never seen a "flow break" while executing a function to go back and then forward and continue. I like the learning part but it's confusing for a noob..

Comment: It would be _much_ better if you posted your code _as code_, not a screenshot.

Comment: Okay I will, but will the code line numbering still appear?

Comment: @FirstStep, it won't, but you can always write a comment like `// <-- the error is here`

Comment: Okay give me one sec. Thanks all

Comment: Please include the method signature for `ProcessMeasurement`

Comment: The first screenshot is C#. Those must be different files. Is this C# calling C++?

Comment: Post all the code in the call chain. If it's a "threading thing" we must see all threading code. `await` certainly hints at threading.

Comment: But functions are so big .. do I skip the unnecessary codes and post the whole sequence and and all function name/signatures?

Comment: @usr yes, c# is calling c++ and it was working flawlessly since more than 6 months. Suddenly crashed

Comment: @FirstStep, no, you create a MCVE. By doing so, you might even find the error yourself!

Comment: At least post all the lines where threading or pinvoke is happening and include all the calls in the chain. Replace everything else with `//...`. That get's us started at least.

Comment: @usr I just did. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that calls into ConvertToCalibrationMeasurement? Are you starting any kind of thread? Custom awaitables?

Comment: @usr You mean all ConvertToCalibrationMeasurement() calls in the entire solution?

Comment: The call that is on the path that has the bug.

Comment: @usr It's a Reactive Extension who is calling it. I just posted it and what do you mean by Custom Awaitables?

Comment: Sounds like a typical case of a broken await chain. Make sure that *every single method* in the asynchronous method chain returns a task, and that it awaits all the asynchronous methods it calls. And make sure you're not getting any exceptions that might be messing with your control flow (especially in combination with the "missing await" above). Also, you probably want to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` a whole lot - there's no point in marshalling back to the UI thread all the time, and it might give you reentrancy issues.

Comment: @luaan we just noticed an exception is being thrown somewhere (Please see the new Edit for more details). Still digging. Do you have any idea why would this happen if we never touched the code?

Comment: @usr I think yes we are using Custom Awaitables :( Please see the added information

Comment: It might be a multi-threading issue, among many other options :) Try enabling "break on every exception" in the debugger - if you're not throwing too many exceptions, it can help you to pinpoint the place where the problem is happening, and you'll get the error message and error line as well as the exception type (which isn't all that useful here). Data corruption can make even this ineffective, but you'll still get close - maybe you're corrupting some state due to a prior error, and the following executions break all the worse.

Comment: For whatever reason is, it works as the Release version. No errors and all is good. Do you have any idea @luaan why this happens only in the Debug Version?

Comment: In the debug version, or while running in the debugger? There's a lot of differences when running in the debugger. If you think it's about the debug version, try searching for `#if DEBUG` and similar clauses - maybe you've got some conditional code somewhere.

Comment: @luaan "while running the debugger" and stepping over the code it does this weird behavior and throws an exception + Pops an dialog error on the UI, however a Release version worked completely fine.. I know that we feel better and I am not in front the code now so I will dig more tomorrow. But thanks man and please share with me any of your knowledge about this

Comment: There's plenty of hidden issues that can crop up when running in a debugger. For example, it usually means that things take a lot longer than usual, and timing will be off while threads are frozen and thawed all the time. Maybe there's timeouts or something? As for the "flow breaks", that's the `await` points - since you're not using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, everything is marshalled back to the UI thread (similar to doing `Invoke`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible reasons.

1. You might be running your code two times at the same time. Probably on different threads at the same time (if yes, should be easy to see in the debugger, open the “Threads” view). Probably on the same thread (possible if the thread called await, the implementation started some async operation, the thread got free, and called await again).
2. A VS debugger isn’t always reliable. When debugging multithreaded code, sometimes I see weird addresses, but that’s simply not true. To verify, add logging statement in your line 87, e.g. Debug.WriteLine if that’s C#.

Comment: I monitored the threads windows (I never worked with it). I noticed that the Main Thread changes to be a Worker Thread once going from file 4 to 5 but then gets back to be Main thread once the exception gets thrown, is this normal? (Please see the Edit part for more details). And I wrote Debug.Writeline(result) at line 86 how can I watch its output?

Comment: Debug/windows/output, show output from: Debug

Comment: Do you have any idea why the Release version works normally?

Comment: Well, I don’t even have a complete understanding why do you think Debug version doesn’t.

Comment: Debug version doesn't work, it does the above. However, we built a release version and it worked fine ! Weird but better for the users